# link_to tag used for two controllers with shared (one) view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers (template and estimate) sharing one view action. in the index page i have the following code:

```
- if can? :create, Estimate
  = link_to "New Estimate", eval("new_#{params[:controller].singularize}_path"), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', data: ajax_modal_data("form")
```

I want the link_to "New Estimate" to be changed "New Templates" in the index page when the template controller is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some **notes**: try avoiding `#eval` method in rails, and `params` variable outside of controller code, so:

```
= link_to "New #{env.camelize}", send(:"new_#{env}_path"), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', data: ajax_modal_data("form")
```

and call of controller to render:

```
 render :index, locals: { env: safe_controller_name }

 def safe_controller_name
    controllers = %w(templates estimates)
    if ! controllers.include? params[:controller]
       raise
    end
    params[:controller].singularize
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I tried and got "undefined local variable or method 'env' for #.....errors

Comment: how do you pass it to the view index page?

Comment: it worked once i replaced the view with index, also # was missing in send(:"new_{env}_path"). Thanks for your help

Comment: send(:"new_{env}_path") should be send(:"new_#{env}_path")